# tortoise svn menu problem

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had installed Tortoise SVN on my computer and it gives me the contextual menu in Explorer, but there are only 2 options when i right click on a folder, SVN Checkout and Repo-Browser.
  I've worked with Tortoise SVN (it was preinstalled) before, but I was having some other options like SVN Commit or Get lock, on files that were on the local machine.
  Can someone help me in configuring Tortoise in synchronizing with the server's repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the svn checkout command from the tortoise menu in order to get a local copy of the repository, then the other options will show up when you right click things in that folder

Comment: Glad to help, if you find awnsers on Stack Overflow useful, feel free to mark them as awnsers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which items appear from the "Settings" option in the TSVN Context Menu and then checking/unchecking the items you want to appear:

[image]